# Getting error on joins when trying to get its key.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

Here's my stat model.

```
Stat(id: integer, points: float, user_id: integer, match_id: integer, team_id: integer)
```

For team model

```
Team(id: integer, name: string)
```

I'm getting error on teams.name part here's the error.

`#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db-name.teams.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;`

Sample stat:

```
{id: 1, points: 2, user_id: 1, match_id: 1, team_id: 1}
{id: 2, points: 3, user_id: 3, match_id: 1, team_id: 2}
{id: 3, points: 4, user_id: 1, match_id: 2, team_id: 1}
```

My current code:

```
 sample = Stat
        .joins(:user)
        .joins(:team)
        .select('teams.name as team_name, users.id as user_id, match_id, SUM(points) as points')
        .where(user_id: params[:user_id])
        .group(:match_id)
        .where.not(match_id: nil)
        .order("match_id DESC")
        .limit(10)
```

Comment: To fix my error but i need the same result. I need to display the team name.

Comment: Please add associations in question

Comment: The error is saying , you can't add match_id in group by, try to add group("stats.id")

Comment: The error is saying that the specified column in the `group` clause is not specified correctly or at all in the `select` clause. So, I would suggest change `match_id` in select to `stats.match_id`, also in the group change `:match_id` to `stats.match_id`.